# Display inline correction

Tags: html, css, position, inline, displaytag

Im building a "Contact Us" form on website and encouraged a problem with positioning.This is what Im trying to get : 
[image]

This is what I get in [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Pghz/2596/). When i use float it goes above the footer(which is positioned relative).

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="one">
    <img  src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
    </div>
    <div id="two">
        <p class="test">blah blah</p>
        <form class="test">
            <input type="text"/>
            <input type="text"/>
            <input type="text"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>`
```

Comment: Oops i put wrong JSfiddle url,edited.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your wrapper div style to

```
display: inline;
```

And your inner divs to

```
display: inline-block;
```

Then the inner ones will each show up as a block inside the original, which will automatically move down if the page width becomes too small.

I also put each text field in a separate div so they stack vertically.

**EDIT:** I actually messed it up last time. You also need the absolute positioning and a vertical align for it to display the way you want but also be responsive to the width:

[Here is the JSfiddle updated (again)](http://jsfiddle.net/3Pghz/2605/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the floats.
I've updated the JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3Pghz/2592/

```css
#wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#one,
#two {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
input {
  display: block;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="one">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <p class="test">blah blah</p>
    <form class="test">
      <input type="text" />
      <input type="text" />
      <input type="text" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<style>
#wrapper .text {
position:relative;
bottom:30px;
left:0px;
visibility:hidden;
}

#wrapper:hover .text {
visibility:visible;
}
#one
{ float:left;}

</style>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="one" >
    <img  src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
    </div>
    <div id="two">
        <p class="test">blah blah</p>
        <form class="test">
            <input type="text"/><br>
            <input type="text"/><br>
            <input type="text"/><br>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/3Pghz/2601/

---------- CSS --------

```
#wrapper #one {
    float: left;
    width: 220px
}

#wrapper #two {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}
#wrapper form.test input {
    display: table-cell;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

------------ HTML --------

```
<div id="wrapper"> 
    <div id="one"> <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"> </div> 
    <div id="two"> 
        <p class="test">blah blah</p> 
        <form class="test"> 
            <input type="text"> 
            <input type="text"> 
            <input type="text"> 
        </form> 
    </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```